# Frustrating first experience

Tags: discussion

Just posted my first question on super user (
[Meaning of last 16 characters in WinSxS manifest file names](https://superuser.com/questions/1051316/meaning-of-last-16-characters-in-winsxs-manifest-file-names)) and got immediately downvoted without comment.

Is this question inappropriate or even too complicated for this community ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your question. It's possible that the downvoter thought it was not useful - the tooltip on the downvote button says "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful." I'm not sure there is research that can be done, and the question seems clear to me. It's also possible that the downvoter didn't like the slight mistakes in syntax (like the space between a word and the question mark), which I have fixed for you.

Answer (score 2):

Just because you got a downvote isn't the end of the world. There is no *requirement* that anyone who downvotes should provide some explanation, and there's no way for us to track who downvotes or the reason for those downvotes.

If you're getting a lot of downvotes, questions closed/deleted, etc. then I'd start to worry, but asking a meta question over a single downvote is a bit extreme. Someone just *didn't like your question for some reason*.

But, no, it doesn't look off-topic to me, and it's probably answerable, but perhaps no one knows, judging from the lack of response. I doubt it'll be closed though.